# HBase Table Data Convert to CSV

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

How to  HBase table data to convert .CSV file, im trying to convert table data to csv format , but i couldn't get any code 
hbase001> list
        Table
       sample_data

Comment: Please start by showing us what you've tried so far - otherwise we can only guess at what the problem/solution is.

Comment: thank for replay , i  have a Hbase table their , but i need to convert CSV format , do you have any code ,please explain me

Comment: Please include any code you've tried in your OP. Stack overflow isn't going to write your code for you.

Comment: im not tried any code , im searching code for hbase table to .csv format

Comment: That's great that you're looking for code, but Stack Overflow isn't going to write it for you, and so unfortunately your question doesn't belong here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is designed as a Question and Answer site, where you ask a specific programming-related question (with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and we attempt to answer it. This question does not conform to that guidance.

Comment: ru expert in HBase , defiantly you know the answer, my manager gives me hbase table to convert csv file,  if you don't no the code leave it please thank you

Answer (score 0):

Creating an external Hive table mapped on to HBase table using HBaseStorageHandler can solve your problem ,you can now use "select * from table_name" to get data into a csv table (stored as textfile fields terminted by ','). Please refer the below link for reference.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-Usage

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of ways to solve your task. You can use spark, regular mapreduce or special tools like sqoop. This task is rather trivial and you can implement it by yourself if you learn hadoop. The quickest way for starters to do it is probably sqoop. Please get youself familiar with this power tool and play with it.
Good luck!